# Query to get the maximum ids on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

what will be the query to select disinct rows having the highest id for a pair (sender,receiver), taken columns in any sequence.
that is (sender,receiver)  or (receiver,sender)

My table data

```
_id      sender   receiver    date      message
 1        rohan    deepak    17-01-17   hell
 2        rohan    deepak    18-01-17   hello
 3        deepak   rohan     18-01-17   had i done
 4        anand    shivam    20-01-16   joke
```

Query:

```
Select * from `message` where _id IN (Select max(_id) from
 `message` GROUP BY sender,receiver);
```

OR

Query:

```
Select * from `message` where _id IN (Select max(_id) from
 `message` GROUP BY receiver,sender);
```

gives

```
_id      sender   receiver    date      message
 1        rohan    deepak    17-01-17   hello
 3        deepak   rohan     18-01-17   had i done
 4        anand    shivam    20-01-16   joke
```

See here id 1&3 are of same pair but it gives different max _id so i get 2 rows instead of 1 for pair(rohan,deepak)

i required output as:

```
_id      sender   receiver    date      message
 3        deepak   rohan     18-01-17   had i done
 4        anand    shivam    20-01-16   joke
```

as 3,4 are max(_id) for unique pairs

So can anyone help me out to get this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure its the most efficient, but you can call your table twice with `UNION`, and change the sender -receiver order:

```
Select * from `message` where _id IN (
  Select max(_id) from (
    Select _id, sender, receiver from `message`
     UNION
    Select _id, receiver, sender from `message`
  ) GROUP BY receiver,sender
);
```

Similar worked for me, but I use Oracle; you might need little tuning on your side.